# How to stop Rake from unnecessarily executing file tasks with dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

File tasks in Rake should only be executed when the file they are named after doesn't exist yet.

I have one file task that builds a `directory` and one file task that creates a `file` within that directory. Now the file cannot be created unless the directory exists, so I set the directory task to be a dependency for the file task:

```
file "directory" do
  mkdir_p "directory"
end

file "file" => "directory" do
  touch "directory/file"
end

desc "Create file"
task build: "file"
```

When I first run the `build` task here, everything works according to plan: first the directory is created, then the file:

```
$ rake -t build
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Invoke file (first_time)
** Invoke directory (first_time)
** Execute directory
mkdir -p directory
** Execute file
touch directory/file
** Execute build
```

When I run it a second time after both the file and its containing directory have been created, I would expect Rake to do nothing (`not_needed`), because all the files the file tasks are related to are already existent. Instead, the directory task is skipped but the file task is executed:

```
$ rake -t build
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Invoke file (first_time)
** Invoke directory (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute file
touch directory/file
** Execute build
```

How can I make Rake not run the `file` task if `directory` and `file` both already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *file* task is wrong. It states, as if it creates `file` in root directory, but actually it creates `file` in `directory` directory. Rake checks if the `file` exists in the root directory, and as it is not there, runs the task. For it to work properly you need to rename the *file* task:

```
file "directory/file" => "directory" do
  touch "directory/file"
end

desc "Create file"
task build: "directory/file"
```

This way Rake check the right file for existence and does not run the 'directory/file' task.

```
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Invoke directory/file (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke directory (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute build
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Sadly this problem was introduced only in my example, my underlying problem was a different one, where all the task names matched their pathes. It seems I managed to solve the actual problem by not using a simple `file` task for the directory, but instead using the special `directory` task Rake also offers.